# Window briefly appears/disappears when debugging .net core winforms application

Tags: winforms, .net-core

I am not new to WinForms, but just created my first WinForms app in .net core 3.1.

Every time I run the project in the debugger it flashes a window for a brief moment that immediately disappears. My main form shows up and everything works normally, so it's not a big deal but it's just kind of annoying and I'm wondering it that's supposed to happen.

Anyone else experiencing this or know what it is?

Comment: Do you have any third party components running in trial mode?

Comment: @RossBush No sir.